# update table by getting a value from another view Yii

Tags: php, oracle, yii

i'm using yii framework here. i need help, how to put a value to my textfield and update my table while the value that i take is from the other view.

i have a main table (A) where this table have `id, proj_name, design_start_date, design_end_date`. while my other table (B) have `id, design_start, design_end`. value of `design_start_date` will update by the minimum date from `design_start` and `design_end_date` will update by the maximum date from `design_end`

can anybody help me? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
update 
tableA a
set design_start_date = 
(select min(design_start) from tableB b where b.id= a.id),
design_end_date = 
(select max(design_end) from tableB b where b.id= a.id)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. anyway is it for my query? i need the code for my controller in php

Comment: yes it is your query but i cant help with controller

Comment: my query have works well, but its not updating when i use it in my controller and i need code to make this done. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

i have found my solution, thanks..
if u need some maybe this could help

in my table A view:

```
$start_date = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select * from (select design_start from B Order by design_start asc) where rownum = 1")->queryScalar();

$end_date = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select * from (select design_end from B Order by design_end asc) where rownum = 1")->queryScalar();
```

somehow the textfield u want to fill with that value:

```
<?php echo $form->textfield($model, 'design_start_date', array('id'=>'designstartDate', 'value'=>$start_date))>
<?php echo $form->textfield($model, 'design_end_date', array('id'=>'designendDate', 'value'=>$end_date))>
```

value will be generated in textfield but u still have to click the save button so it will save to table A